# Am I misunderstanding reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a grouped table view where I want to reload a particular row.  When I call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: the row disappears completely from the table view.  Is there something else I need to be doing?

```
//this is the method doing the reload
-(void)setDurationTableViewCell:(NSString *)dur {

    self.workoutDuration = dur;
    NSIndexPath *durPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
    NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:durPath];
    [woTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}//end setDurationTableViewCell


//this is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method if it has anything to do with my issue
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        //workout comments
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"workoutCommentsCell"];
        if (nil == cell) { 
            cell = workoutCommentsCell;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
        }

    }else if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        //difficulty
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"workoutDifficultyCell"];
        if (nil == cell) { 
            cell = workoutDifficultyCell;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Difficulty: %@", self.workoutDifficulty];

    }else if (indexPath.row == 2) {

        //workoutDate
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"workoutDateCell"];
        if (nil == cell) { 
            cell = workoutDateCell;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@", self.workoutDate];

    }else if (indexPath.row == 3) {

        //workoutDuration
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"workoutTimerCell"];
        if (nil == cell) { 
            cell = workoutTimeCell;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Duration: %@", self.workoutDuration];

    }//end else-if


    return cell;

}//end cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try wrapping your ReloadRowsAtIndexPaths inside

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

e.g

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[woTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView endUpdates]
```

Comment: What helped me is totally remove reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: and left only 
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: Just for information. I tried wrapping several `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` in one `beginUpdates` `endUpdates` block, but this resulted in an awkward behavior with the `accessoryView`, which was a `UISwitch` which is stored in a property. And when reading the documentation begin/endUpdates is used for insertion, deletion and selection.

Answer (score 5):

I recently started learning iPhone SDK and most probably i can´t give you the answer... But, don´t you have to replace the code in the `if (nil == cell)` blocks with

```
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 
reuseIdentifier:@"workoutTimerCell"] autorelease];
```

Comment: +1 I agree with @CodeSeavers. It looks like you aren't allocating any cells. Even if you're allocating something to `workoutDifficultyCell`, you need to allocate more of them for the other cells in the table. I recommend you review TableViewSuite on Apple's website to learn more.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and apparently setting `withRowAnimation:` to `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` solved it for me.
Can't say why, but otherwise the cell makes a nice animation and is then gone.

Answer (score 3):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    });
```