# UITableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths crash when table data gets updated

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash

I have a table view with each rows having image and some text. The images are loaded asyc. As soon as image is fetched from server, the delegate methods gets called. The delegate method contains the index path which initiated the image fetching, so that I can reload only those cells. I have extra check to make sure that once the image is fetched, the data source contains enough data so that index path doesn't go out of bounds. Despite setting this condition the app crashes.

There is a chance that my table data gets updated before the image is fetched. I know this is cause of the issue, but I am not sure why this is making a crash despite adding a check before 
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths?

The error is:

> Fatal Exception NSInternalInconsistencyException Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 2. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Can some one share any inputs on this?

Code snippet that reloads the table

```
// this method will be called on main thread

- (void)loadImageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)inIndexPath {

      if(inIndexPath.row < dataSource.count) {

            [self.listView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:inIndexPath]
                                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

      }

}
```

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722197/am-i-misunderstanding-reloadrowsatindexpaths if that doesn't work can you post code for - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Did check the link that you'd had posted, I have done wrapping the reload API b/w begin updates and end updates API call, but I am not sure that will that solve the crash issue.

Comment: If you do [self.listView reloadData] is it still crashing?  Which line is it crashing on?

Comment: I need to test this, will update you on this.

Comment: @yan: Now the app is not crashing, thanks for the help.

Comment: but reloading Data will slow down the performance of UI and makes your scrolling laggy. Does it not ?